# VB 2012: Add new, Modify record MSACCESS using ADO recordset

Tags: vb.net

I tried the below code, 
1) Button3_Click()...For add new record, there is no error message but no record is added to database
2) Button2_Click()...For update record a error message is shown "Could not load type 'ADODB.FieldsToInternalFieldsMarshaler' from assembly 'WindowsApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Could somebody help in this.

```
Public Class Form1



Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'update 1st record
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection()
    cn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Test.mdb;"
    cn.Open()

    rs.Open("SELECT * FROM Users", cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic)


    rs.MoveFirst()
    rs.Fields("EmpName").Value = "AAAAA"
    rs.Fields("EmpId").Value = "222"
    rs.UpdateBatch()

    rs.Close()
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'add new Record

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection()
    cn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Test.mdb;"
    cn.Open()

    rs.Open("SELECT * FROM Users", cn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic)

    Dim fieldsArray(1) As Object
    fieldsArray(0) = "EmpName"
    fieldsArray(1) = "EmpId"
    Dim values(1) As Object
    values(0) = "4"
    values(1) = "as"

    rs.AddNew(fieldsArray, values)
    rs.UpdateBatch()

    rs.Close()
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

See my code which I tested and it worked: Table1 has two fields. I add a row with two values.

```
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "Table1", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields(1) = "a"
    rs.Fields(2) = "b"
    rs.UpdateBatch
```

Comment: I think this is vbscript, require this for VB2012

Comment: No it is vba, ADODB are same always.